# Ring $R[x]$ with ideal $I=P[x]$ that $P$ is maximal ideal of $R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be an commutative and unitary ring that not field and $P$ is maximal ideal of $R$. Now let $I=P[x]$ be an ideal of $R[x]$. Is $I$ is prime? Is $I$ is maximal?

Comment: Hint: Show that $R[x]/P[x] \cong (R/P)[x].$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Try to show that $R[x]/P[x] \cong (R/P)[x]$. In general, for any ideal $\alpha \subset R$, $R[x]/\alpha[x] \cong (R/\alpha)[x]$. Using this show that if $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$, then $P[x]$ is a prime ideal of $R[x]$, but never maximal. To see the latter, observe that for a domain $D$, $D[x]$ is never a field.